# TI sensor tag clone

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, sensors, ibeacon

I'm planning to design a custom sensor tag using a CC2540 ibeacon module and IMU unit. Can I burn TI's sensor tag firmware directly to the ibeacon module without doing changes to the source code, or do I have to configure I2C communication part in the source code? If so please let me know how to do it.

Regards.

[ibeacon module I'm using](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/2pcs-lot-Bluetooth-module-4-0-BLE-cc2540-cc2541-ibeacon-free-shipping/1629844942.html)

[IMU sensor I'm planning to intergrate](http://www.ebay.com/itm/10DOF-IMU-MPU6050-HMC5883L-BMP085-Flight-Control-Gyroscope-Acceleration-Compass-/360805656195?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item5401b16683)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any more information about the iBeacon module you're using. It's hard to tell if it's set up so you can plug n play sensors. The information in the product description is not very helpful.

It looks like the iBeacon module you're using is relying on the System-on-Chip solution that the CC2540 provides. If this is true in order to modify the source you'll need the IAR 8051 Compiler which requires purchasing a license at around $3,000 US dollars.

It's hard to say for certain without more information about that module. Do you have a spec sheet for that module?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Light Blue Bean instead of that module. It has iBeacon mode options available from the start. https://punchthrough.com/bean/ibeacon-setup/

It is programmable with the Arduino IDE, with over the air updates. So you won't have to deconstruct your project to reprogram it, and you won't have to buy the IAR compiler either. The Beans even have the I2C communication busses built in, as well as an onboard accelerometer! https://punchthrough.com/bean/arduino-users-guide/

Comment: That's really interesting